# Deleting sub-directories from multiple parent folders in Windows

Tags: windows, directory

I'm looking for a script in Windows that will delete subdirectories older than 7 days but for multiple parent folders, I don't want to list them one by one in my batch file.

My folders are structured like this:
C:\appfolder\person1\
C:\appfolder\person2\
...
C:\appfolder\personN\

I want to delete everything older than 7 days that each person has in their individual folders. I couldn't find any script that would look inside and not delete each personN folder as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you written so far? Which parts aren't working? Any relevant error messages?

Comment: Try `for /R "C:\appfolder" %G in (*.*) do @echo %~tG "%~G"` from command line for the first look (in a batch script double the `%` sign, use `%%G`, `%%~G` etc.)  Maybe you could find more info at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) rather than here.